# How can I delete a particular row from the table in a SQLquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How can I delete a particular row from the table in a **SQLquery**. I used **primary key** and **Foreign key** in this table. I am using **`Oracle 11G`**.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like an internet search before asking this question

Comment: You don't delete rows from a *query*, you delete them from a *table*.

Answer (score 2):

its very simple,
may be you need some reference:
http://psoug.org/reference/delete.html

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE columnname= 'value';

Comment: thank you for your immediate response, i used this " delete from Employees where Emp_ID=12; " and can you know me how to delete a particular record in a row please?

Comment: it should work... the above statement deletes particular record(12) details from table Employees

Comment: you asking to delete column  Right?  `update users set user_adr = ''
where user_id = 'userid'`

Comment: Yeah It's deleted the entire row, but I am asking in a row(for ex: empid=12 (it'a row) i need to change the City name)

Answer (score 1):

you asking to delete column Right?
     `update employee set city_name = '' where empid = '12'`

Try this...
This will make the column to `NULL`

Comment: The title says "row". The post doesn't even mention columns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example

> You are having a table named cars 
>        columns are car_id, car_model, car_colour

```
car_id           car_model         car_colour
 234              hyundai           red
 345              Nano              white
 565              Maruthi           black
 888              BMW               brown
 895              Audi              Blue
 234              hyundai           red_blue
 345              Nano              white_yellow
 565              Maruthi           black_shade
 888              BMW               brown_king
 895              Audi              Blue_red
```

now here you want to delete the **brown_king** colour row, then you want to type the below query

> delete from *table_name* where *column_name* = 'condition'
>
> delete from cars where car_colour ='brown_king'

This will delete that particular row in this table.